# checking two object instances to see if they are the same

Tags: c#, properties, compare, equality

i need to compare two objects but compare a number of their properties in one hit.
this is not for sorting, but instead to confirm whether anything has changed; as one is the old saved instance, and the second is a newly imported instance of the same thing

i assume this is best served by writing a custom comparer. just am a bit confused as to whether to do `IComparer`, or `IComparable`, or what tbh.

thanks

nat

Comment: That's a good question.  All of the different comparing confuses me too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only have a single definition of equality for your class, you don't really need to implement any interface:  simply override the `Equals`method. Best practice though, would be to implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)and to override `GetHashCode` sensibly (if you don't override the hash-code, equality will misbehave when collection classes, LINQ methods etc. use it as a pre-condition for equality). Here's a sample implementation:

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode()) ^ Age;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Person);
    }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        return other != null && other.Name == Name && other.Age == Age;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do:

```
Person savedPerson = ...
Person importedPerson = ...

bool hasChanged = !savedPerson.Equals(importedPerson);
```

---

If, on the other hand, you do have lots of different definitions of equality for different circumstances, your best bet would be to write up different [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)implementations. Here's a sample implementation:

```
public class AgeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return (x == null || y == null) ? x == y : x.Age == y.Age;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj == null ? 0 : obj.Age;
    }
}
```

In this case, the check will look like:

```
Person savedPerson = ...
Person importedPerson = ...
IEqualityComparer<Person> comparer = ...

bool hasChanged = !comparer.Equals(savedPerson, importedPerson);
```

Comment: How does the IEquatable Equals differ than the Equals defined on Object?

Comment: looks like its the IEqualityComparer for me in this instance then, as i need to check a number of properties of my person.ie.managerID, phoneNumber, location.. etc and if any of them have changed i need the compare to return false.. unless i'm missing something?
but maybe i am jsut misunderstanding what gethashcode does..

Comment: so like this?!

myPersonComparer: IEqualityComparer<Person>{
public bool Equals(Person x, Person y){
if(x==null || y==null)return false;
if(x.prop != y.prop) return false;
if(x.prop2 != y.prop2) return false;
//..etc
return true;

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need your type to implement IComparable. [Here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/d5a8c475-2395-41e7-9c19-aa2edb23422e/custom-sorting-with-icomp.aspx) is a sample on how to do it.

Comment: Your link points back to this thread.  That's an example of recursion, not IComparable ;)

Comment: and i would return 0 for the same and either 1/-1 for not.. as this is not a sorting comparer.. it makes no odds to me.. ?!
ie.
public int CompareTo(object other){
if(!this.stringprop.equals(other.stringprop))return -1;
if(!this.stringprop2.equals(other.stringprop2)) return -1;
and so on.. until
// all is well
return 0;
??

Answer (score 0):

As you have alluded to IComparable is typically used for sorting.

In this case you would want to overload the comparison operator: ==

Because the reverse comparison should also be valid, this implies you must also overload the != operator.

When you overload == and !- you are also expected to override Equals and GetHashCode.

A decent C# book should explain the details.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to implementing the IComparable interface would be to override the Equals and GetHashCode functions.

Answer (score 0):

That is about how you want to perform compare operation. You can do the operation in both ways:

```
public void Method()
{
    Foo p1 = new Foo();
    Foo p2 = new Foo();

    p1.CompareTo(p2);
    FooComparer c = new FooComparer();
    c.Compare(p1, p2);
}

class Foo : IComparable
{
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class FooComparer : IComparer<Foo>
{
    public int Compare(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I prefer using IComparer as seperation of concerns. Foo is my class, I have some busines needs on it. If I want to compare some Foos, I use FooComparer. For your situation you can return the number of changed properties from Compare method. If Compare method return 0. Then two Foos are same.

As I said. That is completely how you want to perform the action I think. Overriding Equality Operators are also good solution. Implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` is another solution.